# How do I compare whether two numbers have 1 number of difference between them?

Tags: bash

**Explaining my algorithm:**

I'm trying to find out whether My current job for e.g. Write(W) is the same as my previous job, if my current job (W) is the same as my previous job (W) then check whether there's 1 integer of difference between them, for e.g. if the previous job was W9 and my current job is either W8 or W10, then append 0 to my seek array.

I've tried almost every way I could find on the internet to compare integers but none of them work, I continue to receive an invalid arithmetic syntax error when trying to compare current and previous job.

Any ideas?

```
# Jobs
lastJob=""
currentJob=""
lastNumber=0
currentNumber=0

# Arrays 
seek=()
RW=()
shift 3
# Reads final into array
while IFS= read -r line
do
        Job+=($line)
done < ./sim.job

#-----------------------------------
# Single HDD Algorithm
#-----------------------------------
for (( i=0; i<=${#Job[@]}; i++ ));
do 
        currentString="${Job[$i]}"
        currentJob=${currentString:0:1}
        currentNumber=${currentString:1:3}

        if [[ $currentJob == $lastJob ]]
        then    
                if [[ $currentNumber -eq $lastNumber-1 ]] || [[ $currentNumber -eq $lastNumber+1 ]]
                then
                        seek+=(0)
                        RW+=(60)
                else
                        seek+=(5)
                        RW+=(60)
                fi
        else
                        seek+=(5)
                        RW+=(60)  
        fi

        lastString="${Job[$i]}"
        lastJob=${lastString:0:1}
        lastNumber=${currentString:1:3}
done
```

**This prints output:**

```
#-----------------------------------
# Print Information
#-----------------------------------
for (( i=0; i<${#Job[@]}; i++ ));
do
        echo -e "${Job[$i]}:${seek[$i]}:${RW[$i]}"
done
```

**Expected Output:**

```
R9:5:60
W9:5:60
W10:0:60
R11:0:60
R13:5:60
R18:5:60
R19:0:60
R20:0:60
R21:0:60
```

**Actual Output:**

```
") syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
R9:5:60
W9:5:60
W10::
R11::
R13::
R18::
R19::
R20::
R21::
```

**sim.job file (Input):**

```
R9
W9
W10
R11
R13
R18
R19
R20
R21
```

Comment: Without the input I don't think we'll be much help, so please edit your question to include an example of what that looks like. But note that there's a carriage return in the middle of the error message (which is why it goes back to the left of the screen and overwrites the beginning of the message with the end) - it may help to strip those out of your input file.

Comment: @MarkReed I've included the input file

Comment: the code works for me and I get the desired output sans any error messages; along similar lines of what @MarkReed mentioned, I'm wondering if there's a rogue `\r` somewhere in the mix ... if not in the data file then perhaps in the shell script itself; for both `sim.job` and your shell script, does `od -c <filename> | tr ' ' '\n' | grep '\r'` return any lines of `\r`? if so, consider running `dos2unix <filename>` and then run the `od/tr/grep` again to see if the `\r` is now gone; alternatively, go straight to `dos2unix <filename>` and then see if the script works sans error

Comment: @markp-fuso `sim.job came back with 9x " /r "` `HDD.sh came back with 46 " r "` without the backslash, I had tried to remove the " \r " lines using dos2unix but the command isn't recognised and I have no access to administrator..

Comment: I'm assuming your `/r` was a typo and should be `\r`; you can emulate the character removal portion of `dos2unix` with `tr -d '\r' < filename`; while `dos2unix` will replace the source file, you'll need to direct the output from `tr` to a new file and then move that file back to overwrite the original (obviously make sure the new file looks good before moving/overwriting the source file); better yet, move the source file out of the way ... `mv srcfile srcfile.dos` (?) ... until you've confirmed you no longer need it

Comment: @markp-fuso `tr -d '\r' < sim.job > sim.job` this fixed the issue... I've just wasted 4 hours of my life debugging code that already worked..

Comment: good to hear it worked, though I'm always a bit hesitant to have a single command use the same file name for input and output (yeah, I know, it's 'ok' in some cases, but it's generally a bad habit to get into 'cause one day you'll overwrite/wipe-out some big file - perhaps that script you've spent 3 days 'perfecting'? -  that'll be hard to regen); as for wasting 4hrs today ... hopefully it'll pay for itself in the future when you see `\r` behavior ... "ah, yeah, I need to run `dos2unix` on that" (or "what was that `tr` command markp told me to use?")

Comment: Yeah, to echo what @markp said, the safer way to do that would be something like `tr -d '\r' < sim.job >sim.job.tmp && mv sim.job.tmp sim.job`.  Or even better, `mv sim.job sim.job.bak && tr -d '\r' <sim.job.bak >sim.job` so you still have a backup of the pre-`tr` file in case you mess up the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rogue `\r` were found in my input file, to solve this I used the commands:

1. To check if `\r` are in the file: `od -c <filename> | tr ' ' '\n' | grep '\r'`
2. To remove rogue `\r` use: `tr -d '\r' < filename`

Thanks again @mark-fuso